# Change From address based on Reply-To

Tags: office365, exchange-server

We currently have onprem exchange that has a custom plugin to change the from address to the reply to address for certain email address.

Could something like this be implemented on exchange online?

Comment: This is for incoming emails. The From Address is always the same but the reply to address could be anything...

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where you wish to do this.
Is it when the mail is incoming into your organisation?

In that case your could either look into changing the properties of the mail header through Exchange Mailflow Rules.

If we are talking about something the user does on their end, it is possible to develop Outlook add-ins that can be both in the Outlook client and Outlook Online (OWA).

Comment: This would only be for incoming email.  Is there any documentation on Mailflow Rules to do something like this?